# Yii2: How to pass associative array as commandline argument?

Tags: yii2

The [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-console#arguments) explains how to use arrays as commandline arguments (by providing a comma-separated list of strings), however this only works for a 1-dimensional indexed array of strings:

```php
// The command "yii example/add test" will call "actionAdd(['test'])"
// The command "yii example/add test1,test2" will call "actionAdd(['test1', 'test2'])"
public function actionAdd(array $name) { ... }
```

But how do I pass multi-dimensional *associative* arrays as commandline arguments without relying on hacky json-based workarounds?

At the very least I would like to be able to do something like `$ yii example/add "foo=bar"` that would execute `actionAdd(['foo'=>'bar'])`. Eventually I would like to also have the ability to do this with nested values (eg. `foo.bar=5` being translated to `['foo'=>['bar'=>5]]`).

Answer (score 1):

There is such code in \yii\console\Controller::bindActionParams

```
$args[$i] = $args[$i] === '' ? [] : preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $args[$i]);
```

So, by default parsing only for comma separated values (non-associative).
You can override this method according to your requirements.

But the regexps will be too complex as for me.
I advice to use json string for input and then do json_decode().